# How to display Discordian date?

Tags: date

I am a strong believer in Discordianism. Yet most mostly I am confronted with the time measurement of pesky heathens.

How do I know what date it really is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ ddate
Today is Prickle-Prickle, the 41st day of Discord in the YOLD 3179
```